Supplementary qualitative variable labels in FactoMinR?
Does anyone know how to work the quali.sup labels on a biplot in FactoMinR / FactoExtra?
The manual says it is possible to specify these variables on the labels with label = "quali" but it just removes all the labels as if you had used labels = none instead.
This dataset comes with the package and has row labels but still does not work.
library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)
data("decathlon2")
testcomp <- PCA(decathlon2[,c(1:5,13)], graph = F, quali.sup = "Competition")
fviz_pca_biplot(testcomp, axes = c(1,2), label = "quali")

I've tried changing the factor to character data type but no luck. It seems to work fine with habillage but not labeling.
